# How do I install/update the Trusted Certificate Store on a Lenovo IdeaTab?

Tags: certificates

Most of the tutorials I have found either allow you to open a file browser to browse to the cert(that button isn't visible on my device), or install from an SD card. I tried the install from SD card option, but it just presents a toast that no certificate was detected, even when I moved it into the root folder of the SD Card.

It isn't a special cert for an app that I am trying to install, I am just attempting to install the `ISRG Root X1.der` cert, which is required for modern sites using Let'sEncrypt(a sizeable part of the internet).

Or is there a way for me to force the device to pull all of the new/modern certs from Google?

Comment: What Android version is installed and is the tablet rooted?

Comment: @Robert the device is running Android 4.1, and it is not rooted. I’m just trying to get it working for a family member

Comment: On Android 4.1 you can simply install a root CA certificate as user certificate. But that won't help you much because the main problem is that Android 4.1 does AFAIR not support TLS 1.2. Some Google apps has been updated to use an additional crypto library for TLS 1.2, but most apps don't use this provider and thus don't support TLS 1.2.

Comment: @Robert, I’ll take my chances with installing it, and hoping most sites still have TLS 1.1 support. The issue is that I can’t seem to figure out **how** to install the cert. I can toggle existing certs on and off, but in the menu, the only option I see is to install from an SD card, but it seems it doesn’t detect the cert from there anyway.

Comment: Most likely because your certificate uses a very uncommon file extension. Usually certificates have file extension `.cer` or `.pem` not `.der`.

Comment: @Robert I found the cert as a `.pem` [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem). Weirdly though, it still throws the same toast error: `No certificate files found on the SD card.` And, I made sure to put it at the root of the SD card too, in case it doesn't check subfolders.

Comment: You can try to pack it into an .p12 file (PKCS#12). This format is actually designed for private and secret keys but it can also contain certificates. Use e.g. https://keystore-explorer.org create a new PKCS#12 file without password and then import the certificate into this p12 file.

Comment: @Robert, that got me a little farther. When I click on the cert, it brings up a prompt to enter a password. When I don't enter anything, it throws an "incorrect password" error. When I do set a password, and use said password, same thing.

Comment: PKCS#12 supports different encryption algorithms and also it seems to make a difference between no password and empty password, so a lot of possible problems. I also read that Android does not support PEM, so I would recommend to use the `.der` certificate and rename it to `.cer` or `.crt`. Such certificates should be found by Android.